# Override styled component parent div properties in child

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

In a React application I am working with the following `div` structure using `styled` components.

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <Image/>
    <Text/>
  </Child>
</Parent>

const Parent = styled.div`
 ...
 ...
 padding = 25px 5px;
`;

const Child = styled.div`
  padding: 0px;
`;
```

**Problem:** I have to override the parent div properties (`padding`) in child component. I cannot `extend` the Parent div in child to override because Parent has lot more properties which should not be applied into child. I need to force `padding: 0px` in child component.

**Tried:** I tried the followings but didn't work since its a new individual `div`.

```
 const Child = styled.div`
   && {
        padding: 0px;
   }
`; 

   const Child = styled.div`
     padding: 0px !important;
`;
```

Is there a way to override the parent properties into child `styled` component without extending parent div into child?

Comment: Why would your `Child` have `padding` styling if you don't specify any ?

Comment: There is no padding for the child, the padding comes from the parent, what do you expect to happen? Can you make a producible example? Try using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-starter-n2dem)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, you add padding for `Parent` children, and then you want to override it from the Child component?

Answer (score 1):

You can't target a parent `class` from a child, instead, you should do it from the parent itself.

In this example, without overriding in `Parent`, the child will have `padding: 10px` and the green background will be revealed.

```
const Child = styled.div`
  background-color: palegreen;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const Parent = styled.div`
  background-color: palevioletred;
  padding: 1rem;
  ${Child} {
    padding: 0px;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-williams-w3nh8]